# WebApi2.0 DelegatingHandler - error - index was out of bounds of the array

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a webapi 2.0 project. I am registering two delegating handler in webapiconfig.cs. Sometimes it throws error "Index was out of bounds of the array" and the stact trace shows - error at System.Collections.GenericList.Add(T item) at handler1 at handler2. I am also using unityconfig that i am registering at Application_Start in Global.asax and I am registering WebApiconfig at Application_Start in Global.asax
I dont know why such strange behavior as it is working fine for most of the time but sometimes it throws this error.

My Code in WebApiconfig.cs is as below  -

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        config.EnableCors();

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new Handler1(););

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new Handler2());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    }
```

Code for two handlers are as below -

```
public class Handler1 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {


        string routeTemplate = ((IHttpRouteData[])request.GetConfiguration().Routes.GetRouteData(request).Values["MS_SubRoutes"])
                                .First().Route.RouteTemplate.ToString();



        IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(new Guid()), new string[] { "myRole" });
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(
        (task) =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;

            return response;
        }
    );
    }
    }
public class Handler2 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string routeTemplate = ((IHttpRouteData[])request.GetConfiguration().Routes.GetRouteData(request).Values["MS_SubRoutes"])
                                .First().Route.RouteTemplate.ToString();

        HttpConfiguration config = request.GetConfiguration();
        config.Filters.Add(new Filter1());


        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(
        (task) =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;

            return response;
        }
    );
    }
}
```

Can someone please help with what I should do?

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace. (And ideally format the code in your question more readably too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was add filters inside handler.
config.Filters.Add(new Filter1());

Added the filter in GlobalConfig and everything is running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks very suspicious

```cs
string routeTemplate = ((IHttpRouteData[])request.GetConfiguration()
                               .Routes.GetRouteData(request)
                               .Values["MS_SubRoutes"])
                               .First()
                               .Route.RouteTemplate.ToString();
```

Because "MS_SubRoutes" thing could not exists, so you need to break that codeion different blocks to validate. Also you need to be sure that the collection has at least one member  so you need to control this issue too.

```cs
var ms_SubRoutes = (IHttpRouteData[])request
    .GetConfiguration()
    .Routes
    .GetRouteData(request)
    .Values["MS_SubRoutes"];

string routeTemplate;

//Verify if "MS_SubRoutes" are part of the request
if (ms_SubRoutes != null)
{
    try
    {
        routeTemplate = ms_SubRoutes.First()
                                    .Route
                                    .RouteTemplate.ToString();
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfRangeException ior)
    {
        //Do something
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Do something
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes JuanK I have tested the solution...it works for 99.9% cases but some time it breaks...The error is at Config.Filters.Add in Handler2.